# Can't get terminal (VSCode) to run my code in C++

Tags: c++, terminal

I am new in C++. I like VSCode very much. I want to run my C++ code in VSCode and so I am using MinGW and Run Code Extension of VSCode.

MinGW setup worked and I could also run my C++ code in the output terminal in VSCode, but when I enabled Code Runner in the settings to run my code in the terminal (so that I can take inputs), I am getting this error:

> PS C:\Users\nothu\Projects> cd "c:\Users\nothu\Projects" ; if ($?) { g++ 8.UserInputs.cpp -o 8.UserInputs } ; if ($?) { .\8.UserInputs }

While my code was running fine in the terminal to get some user input, one day it just stopped working and started asking me how I wanted to open the file when I tried to run the code. It showed options such as look for app on microsoft store, notepad and visual studio code. I thought it might be a one time thing, but neither the notepad option nor the visual studio code option has worked.

Here is a copy of the code I am trying to run,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

    // cout << (insertion operator)
    // cin >> (extraction operator)

int main(){

    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string food;
    std::string hobby;

    std::cout << "What's your full name?: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    //std::getline (std::cin >>std::ws, name);
    std::cout << "What's your age?: ";
    std::cin >> age;

    std::cout << "What's your favorite food?: ";
    std::cin >> food;

    std::cout << "What's a hobby of yours you love doing?: ";
    std::cin >> hobby;
    //std::getline (std::cin >>std::ws, hobby);

    std::cout << "Hello " << name << "!" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "You are " << age << " years old!" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Your favorite food is " << food << "!" <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "A hobby you love doing is " << hobby << "! That's a good one!";

    return 0;
}
```

I know it's not an issue with the code since the code ran fine before I encountered this problem.
Tried closing  and reopening VSCode, uninstalling and reinstalling, creating new files, renaming files, deleting old files, wiping settings from "settings.json", and looking online for some answers but i cant find anything that might help.

Comment: That is not an error, it's the command that CodeRunner is using to run your code.

Comment: I'm told CodeRunner has a poor reputation (I wouldn't know) maybe you should just disable it.

Comment: Your program has a very strange name `8.UserInputs`. That will be the cause of the App Store messages. I would start by using a name without an embedded `.`. Maybe try `8_UserInputs` instead. This may not solve the problem but will at least make it easier to find the cause of the problem.